# How to replace None value with "None" string value

Tags: python-3.x

I have a text file that I am trying to write to a JSON file.  Some of the values are returned as None, True or False.  I need to replace None with "None" (string), True with "True" and False with "False"

I tried adding the line

```
data=data.replace(None,"None")
```

However, I get an error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "parse_get_drivers.py", line 17, in <module>
    data=data.replace(None,"None")
TypeError: replace() argument 1 must be str, not None
```

> Here is my script

```
import json
import re
from pprint import pprint
import pandas as pd

inHandler = open('get_drivers.txt', 'r')
outHandler = open('drivers.json', 'w')
data = ''


for line in inHandler.readlines():
    print('src:' + line)
    line = line.replace("}]},","}]},\r")
    data += line
    print('replace:' + line)
    data=data.replace("'", '"')
    data=data.replace(None,"None")

outHandler.write(data)

inHandler.close()
outHandler.close()
```

The required result is to replace None, True and False values with "None", "True" and "False".

Comment: This makes no sense. Use `json.loads`, and especially if you are not loading the JSON, `True`/`False`/`None` should already be string values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should parse the input as JSON instead of parsing it line by line as separate strings, so that you can recursively traverse the data structure to replace `None` (or in JSON's terms, `null`) with `"None"`:

```
def replace(data, search, replacement, parent=None, index=None):
    if data == search:
        parent[index] = replacement
    elif isinstance(data, (list, dict)):
        for index, item in enumerate(data) if isinstance(data, list) else data.items():
            replace(item, search, replacement, parent=data, index=index)
```

so that:

```
import json
d = json.loads('{"a": 1, "b": [1, null], "c": {"d": null}}')
print(d)
replace(d, None, 'None')
print(d)
print(json.dumps(d))
```

outputs:

```
{'a': 1, 'b': [1, None], 'c': {'d': None}}
{'a': 1, 'b': [1, 'None'], 'c': {'d': 'None'}}
{"a": 1, "b": [1, "None"], "c": {"d": "None"}}
```